# .dockerignore file located in subdirectory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerignore

I know I can put a `.dockerignore` file in the same directory as the `dockerfile` to ignore some patterns, and this works. Docker doesn't seem to see `.dockerignore` files recursively down in the directory structure though.

I've got a directory which is a git submodule. I'd like to add things to a `.dockerignore` file down in the submodule so that multiple projects that use this shared repo can inherit it.

Is there a way to manually include a `.dockerignore` file into the current context in the `dockerfile`?

Answer (score 0):

You can not include by reference the `.dockerignore` file form the submodules.

The `.dockerignore` is usually related to a specific development tools and methods, so there is a good chance that the `.dockerignore` will already cover some of the major common files in the submodule as it covers in the main repository.

In case where there are discrepancies, you can add the content from the submodule .dockerignore to your main .dockerignore, corrected for the prefixes that are relevant to the submodule.